# How to run FFmpeg command in Qprocess to make it work?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, ffmpeg, qprocess

I have problem with QProcess. I added FFmpeg and command to Qt process. When I run this and I don't see any changes in folder where should be files .mkv. Somebody said me to add "\n" to the but this don't help. ( I do it on macOS Catalina )

````cpp
void MainWindow::Recording(){

    qDebug() << "Nagrywam!";

    Qrec.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    Qrec.setProgram("/Users/nintyswinty/Desktop/Dev/Qt/build-PlazaPCO-Desktop_Qt_5_15_1_clang_64bit-Debug/ffmpeg");
    Qrec.setArguments({"-framerate", "30", "-f", "avfoundation", "-i", "1", "-f", "avfoundation", "-framerate", "30", "-i", "0", "-c:v", "libx264", "-crf", "0", "-preset", "ultrafast", "~/Desktop/PlazaPCO/" + QString::fromStdString(date) + ".mkv\n"});
    Qrec.start();
    Qrec.waitForFinished();

    qDebug() << "Koniec - nagrywam";

}```
````

Comment: Adding "\n" is not correct

Comment: You may want to print what is in [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError) and check the [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitStatus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitStatus)

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, I do it and... I have nothing. ( this is printed: End: "" ).

Comment: Maybe [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) tells you something. Also does it actually take time to process or is it over in no time?

Comment: It could be that `QString::fromStdString(date)` is not what you expect.

Comment: I qDebug this and this is what I expected: "10-09-20-18:15:13", so I don't know.

Comment: And this take a while, and later stop.

Comment: Did you test the command on a terminal ?

Comment: Yes, and this command normally work

Answer (score 0):

"~" and "\n" created this error. Must use getenv instead of "~' and remove "\n".